# Where should the upload_handler.php be located?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using PHP with a REST API. I'm trying to upload file(s) using AJAX and retrieve a thumbnail.

app.yaml

```
- url: /api/(.*)
  script: api/index.php 
- url: /.*
  script: index.html
```

Javascript: This function triggers when a user selects image(s) to upload.

```
onFileSelect = function($files) {

    for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
        var upload_url = $http.get('/api/upload/new'); //Create a new upload url

        $http.uploadFile({
            url: upload_url,
            file: $files[i]
        }).success(function(pulic_url, status) {
            console.log( pulic_url ); //Print the public url of the uploaded file
        })
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work, the public URLs I get look like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/_ah/upload/adfrhtbnekj...
```

When I make the POST request, it just prints out the index.html file. Which means that it doesn't find my upload_handler.php

Where should I have my upload_handler.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upload handler must be referenced in the app.yaml file as a script. Meaning one should be able to invoke the script like any other (ie make a post/get request since the upload proxy will redirect [make a request] to your app like normal). Your current file only handles api/ and .* to index.html which means when /upload_handler.php is accessed it will be redirected to index.html.

Perhaps you want something like the following

```
- url: /upload_handler.php
  script: upload_handler.php
```

or

```
# next release /(.+\.php)$ will work as well.
- url: /(.+\.php$) 
  script: \1
```